# emmulator-5554 issue

Tags: android

When i try running the simple Hello Android program i get the following message in console
emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.android.hello.HelloAndroid
As a result the program does not run.

Can any one help me out of this...

Thanks in Advance..
sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting adb as suggested [here](http://androidforums.com/android-developers/5398-android-help-emulator-5554-disconnected.html#post102841)

> go to Eclipse IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device--> view menu --> reset adb